# Showing url images in webpart

Tags: web-part, javascript, jquery-ui

I need to display the images of the url typed in a custom webpart .
i.e if i type url name (www.google.com) , atomatically it should display the small logo of google in webpart .Anyone with this idea ? 
For all the url there is associated logo , like sharepoint site when typed , shows an default image.

Comment: Please provide a little more detail in the question about the context of what you're trying to accomplish. Three answers and two of the three have revealed more detail about what you need.

Comment: yea sure , i have a spgridview which has column named MyLinks where i display items from list.There is also a button to add new links .When i click button enter url as(i.e google.com) i should see the favicon of google in gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use spgridview properties to display the image associated with the url.
http://www.google.com/favicon.png gives you the images . display these in hyperlinkbound field of spgridview

Answer (score 2):

make HTTPRequest to entered url and parse received HTML for FAVICON url value if any; then use extracted favicon url to display associated image

Answer (score 0):

Nikhil maybe create a list and link the URL to a logo.
And then use a DataView Webpart to show an image based on the URL.
Hope that helps 
Patrick

Comment: no i need to type any site name and display the logo of the associated site i.e http://www.yahoo.com/favicon.ico

Answer (score 0):

Provided your custom webpart has  text entry , you could enable and use ajax , so that as you type on the fly , your server code can check url and display an image based on the url , in an image control in the same webpart.

Comment: no i am using OOTB newform.aspx , where i enter my url .